# Where is Translation Manager configuration cached (what to restart)?

Tags: translation-manager, worldserver

I'd like to clarify what are the minimum things to restart when making changes to a Translation Manager integration, with WorldServer, for example, for two types of changes:

1. Updates to TranslationManager.xml
2. Changes in the translation management system (e.g. WorldServer) such as new client and project types

In a recent setup I've seen the following.

### TranslationManager.xml

Restarting the Translation Manager service and Content Manager Service Host seemed to make the WorldServer (WS) option available in Tridion Sites, after WS was set up.

### WorldServer changes

To make WS changes (new client and project type) appear in the Sites Translation Manager settings, we:

- Cleared browser cache and also tried a different browser to be sure
- Restarted Translation Manager service
- Restarted COM+ just in case

### Questions:

1. When changing TranslationManager.xml, should we restart the Translation Manager service?
2. Should the Content Manager Service host *also* be restarted for config changes?
3. What's the minimum needed to see changes from WorldServer in the Tridion Sites Publication properties?
4. Will changes eventually be picked up in the Tridion GUI on its own (does Translation Manager check for changes automatically)?

I'm asking to help clarify what might be cached changes (browser vs. service) in the Translation Manager integration and for tips for future configurations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In theory changes in TranslationManager.xml should be applied immediately without restarting anything.

If you do not trust this and want to ensure new configuration is loaded - restart "Translation Manager" service and "Content Manager Service Host" service

For changes in WorldServer - things are cached for 10 min. And should eventually update in UI.

If you can not wait, restart services :)

Comment: Thanks Yuriy! Next time we'll get coffee instead of restarting things! :-)

Comment: Update: I didn't notice we have a `<TranslationSystemCacheRefreshInterval>` setting that defaults to 10 minutes (600 seconds). I'll try reducing this at least during an initial Translation Manager configuration. :-)